# how can i escape a ! (bang/exclamation) in a perl script calling a bash command?

Tags: bash, perl, passwords, escaping, quotes

I am updating a legacy Perl script.  It is pretty straight forward in that it sets some variables and then calls a bash command.  The issue is that I am passing a password that has 2 exclamations in it.  These seem to be getting translated wrong.  Say I have this script:

```
$source_db_ip = "1.2.3.4"; # carl dev/qa
$source_user = 'user1';
$source_password = "password!!";

$destination_db_ip = "5.6.7.8";
$destination_user     = "user2";
$destination_password = "password2!!";

my $status = `pt-table-sync h=$source_db_ip,p='${source_password}',u=$source_user,D=db_name,t=table_name   h=$destination_db_ip,p='$destination_password',u='$destination_user',D=db_name,t=table_name`;
```

This keeps failing.  I know the credentials are correct as I have manually checked them.  So how can I correctly escape the password so it is translated correctly?

Comment: By the way, backticks expect a `sh` command, not a `bash` command.

Comment: By the way, command lines can be seen by anyone on the machine, so including passwords on command lines is a bad idea.

Answer (score 4):

As you can tell by using `` `perl -E'say for \@ARGV' -- ...` ``, the following two strings are passed as arguments:

```
h=1.2.3.4,p=password!!,u=user1,D=db_name,t=table_name
h=5.6.7.8,p=password2!!,u=user2,D=db_name,t=table_name
```

You didn't specify what format you expected, but that looks right. Mind you, I would use `shell_quote` rather than `'$var'`.

```
use String::ShellQuote qw( shell_quote );

my $cmd = shell_quote(
   'pt-table-sync',
   join(',',
      "h=$source_db_ip",
      "p=$source_password",
      "u=$source_user",
      "D=db_name",
      "t=table_name",
   ),
   join(',',
      "h=$destination_db_ip",
      "p=$destination_password",
      "u=$destination_user",
      "D=db_name",
      "t=table_name",
   ),
);

`$cmd`
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion.  i tried it and received an error when executing shell_quote.  but it turns out i had an error in one of my hostnames so didnt pursue the error further.